# Google Analytics management API v3 Service Unavailable

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

we are getting today a "Service Unavailable" response (with status 500) from Google APIs, in particular for the following call

POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3/management/accounts/<ACCOUNT_ID>/webproperties/WEB-PROPERTY-ID/customDataSources

Looking at Analytics service status at seems the service is up & running.

Do you know if something is changed from yesterday?

Our calls are done via scheduled job on a daily bases and yesterday they were responsive

Comment: lookind deeper on the error we are getting from Google, the full response is the following one:
{
   "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal error encounter'ed.",
        "errors": [
              {
                  "message": "Internal error encountered.",
                  "domain": "global",
                  "reason": "backendError",
                  "debugInfo": "detail: \\"generic::invalid_argument: No quota group definition found for group default\\"\\n"
}],
"status":"INTERNAL"}}

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas

Comment: it seems to me we are not yet reached the documented limits, in particular the one described in the section _Data Import API_ (btw, thanks for point us to the limit documentation page!).. It seems that some configuration is missing somehow/somewhere, but I'm not able to find it..

Comment: don't you have a redundant slash in `webproperties//customDataSources` ?

Comment: no, it's just a typo :).. fixing

Comment: We are experiencing the same error since a few hours. Nothing changed in our code since yesterday.

Comment: The error can be reproduced from the online api client in the official doc : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDataSources/list

Comment: Same here. Observing "Internal error encountered." since 19:17 UTC yesterday while querying `/v3/management/accounts/%s/webproperties/%s/customDataSources/%s/uploads`.

Comment: Found related issues on Google's tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168505956
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168505960

Comment: @MatteoBertucelli we're also facing the same issue.

Comment: vote also for https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168537837